# apollo-client-maven-plugin generated code is not resolving when compiled from the command-line

Tags: maven, kotlin, plugins, graphql, apollo-client

I'm unable to get the apollo-client-maven-plugin to compile classes in kotlin from the command-line. I can't tell if the issue is due to the plugin configuration, or perhaps an incorrect, missing, or conflicting dependency. I would appreciate some suggestions to point me in the right direction.

When the *targetLanguage* value is set to JAVA, and I run `mvn clean verify -U`, the introspection works, the code generates, and the tests pass. However, it doesn't compile when I configure the *targetLanguage* to KOTLIN_1_5. The project fails to compile with *"Unresolved reference: graphql"* and *"Not enough information to infer type variable D"* errors during the test-compile phase. Despite this, I'm able to run the tests in Intellij IDEA. The tests compile, run, and pass. After the tests have passed in the IDE, I can then run `mvn verify` from the command-line and the tests will pass until the next clean build.

- This is part of a multi-module java + kotlin project, so I don't think the issue is with the maven-kotlin-plugin itself.
- I've written a sanity test in the project. This is the class which runs into the import issues. I've tried moving this test to a child project, but I experience the same issues downstream.
- I've tried swapping out the different runtime dependencies: apollo-runtime, apollo-runtime-jvm, and apollo-runtime-kotlin.
- I've tried  setting the kotlin plugin's language level and version to 1.5 in the parent pom.

The apollo-client project's pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mycompany.testing</groupId>
            <artifactId>automation-common</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.apollographql.apollo3</groupId>
            <artifactId>apollo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.apollographql.apollo3</groupId>
            <artifactId>apollo-runtime-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.aoudiamoncef</groupId>
                <artifactId>apollo-client-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <services>
                                <myServer>
                                    <sourceFolder>${project.basedir}/src/main/graphql/myServer
                                    </sourceFolder>
                                    <schemaPath>
                                        ${project.basedir}/src/main/graphql/myServer/schema.json
                                    </schemaPath>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.graphql</include>
                                        <include>**/*.gql</include>
                                        <include>**/*.json</include>
                                        <include>**/*.sdl</include>
                                    </includes>
                                    <compilationUnit>
                                        <name>myServer</name>

                                        <outputDirectory>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql-client/myServer/
                                        </outputDirectory>
                                        <testDirectory>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql-client/myServer/test/
                                        </testDirectory>
                                        <debugDirectory>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql-client/myServer/debug/
                                        </debugDirectory>
                                        <operationOutputFile>
                                            ${project.build.directory}/generated/operationOutput/apollo/universe/operationOutput.json
                                        </operationOutputFile>
                                        <generateOperationDescriptors>true
                                        </generateOperationDescriptors>
                                        <compilerParams>
                                            <rootFolders>
                                                <rootFolder>
                                                    ${project.basedir}/src/main/graphql/myServer/
                                                </rootFolder>
                                            </rootFolders>
                                            <schemaPackageName>
                                                com.mycompany.automation.graphql.client
                                            </schemaPackageName>
                                            <packageName>com.mycompany.automation.graphql.client
                                            </packageName>
                                            <codegenModels>OPERATION</codegenModels>
                                            <flattenModels>true</flattenModels>
                                            <generateApolloMetadata>true</generateApolloMetadata>
                                            <generateAsInternal>true</generateAsInternal>
                                            <generateFilterNotNull>false</generateFilterNotNull>
                                            <generateFragmentImplementations>true
                                            </generateFragmentImplementations>
                                            <generateKotlinModels>true</generateKotlinModels>
                                            <generateOptionalOperationVariables>false
                                            </generateOptionalOperationVariables>
                                            <generateQueryDocument>true</generateQueryDocument>
                                            <generateResponseFields>false</generateResponseFields>
                                            <generateSchema>false</generateSchema>
                                            <generateTestBuilders>false</generateTestBuilders>
                                            <moduleName>apollographql</moduleName>
                                            <targetLanguage>KOTLIN_1_5</targetLanguage>
                                        </compilerParams>
                                    </compilationUnit>
                                    <introspection>
                                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                                        <endpointUrl>${introspection.endpoint.url}</endpointUrl>
                                        <schemaFile>${introspection.schema.file}</schemaFile>
                                        <prettyPrint>true</prettyPrint>
                                    </introspection>
                                </myServer>
                            </services>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Parent project's maven-plugin config entry

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.22</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <nowarn>true</nowarn>
              <sourceDirs>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
              </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>

          <execution>
            <id>test-compile</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sourceDirs>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
              </sourceDirs>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

Compile Stack Trace

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-maven-plugin:1.5.20:test-compile (test-compile) on project automation-graphql-support: Compilation failure
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:375)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
Caused by: org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.MavenPluginLogMessageCollector.throwKotlinCompilerException (MavenPluginLogMessageCollector.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinCompileMojoBase.execute (KotlinCompileMojoBase.java:212)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.K2JVMCompileMojo.execute (K2JVMCompileMojo.java:222)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.maven.KotlinTestCompileMojo.execute (KotlinTestCompileMojo.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute2 (MojoExecutor.java:370)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.doExecute (MojoExecutor.java:351)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:171)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:163)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:960)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:196)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

versions:

- apollo-runtime / apollo-runtime-jvm: 3.7.3
- apollo-runtime-kotlin: 3.0.0-dev12
- apollo-api / apollo-api-jvm: 3.7.3
- apollo-client-maven-plugin: 5.0.0
- java: 11.0.16.1 (parent pom)
- kotlin-maven-plugin: 1.7.22 (parent pom)
- kotlin-reflect: 1.7.22 (parent pom)
- kotlin-stdlib: 1.7.22 (parent pom)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed the auto-generated sources weren't picked up by the compiler. Added the destination folder of the generated code to a sourceDir entry:

```
                            <sourceDirs>
                                <sourceDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/graphql-client</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                                <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                            </sourceDirs>
```